# dvajs model namespace or state not saw in props.state or redux devtools

Tags: reactjs, umijs, dvajs

i work on (dvajs+umijs+reactjs) project ,issue in this project is dva model state not saw in my function props or redux devtools, All required or related file below .

src/pages/Model/HomeData.js

```
export default {
namespace: 'Todo',
state: {
    Todo:"Todo data",
    id:"112334"
}
};
```

src/pages/Home/Home.js

```
import { connect } from 'dva'
import React from 'react'
function Home(props) {
    console.log(props);
    return (
        <div>
            Home
        </div>
    )
}
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        state:state
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Home)
```

.umirc.js

```
import routeConfig from "./config/routeConfig";
export default {
  treeShaking: true,
  routes: routeConfig,
  plugins: [
    ['umi-plugin-react', {
      antd: true,
      dva: {
        immer: true
      },
      dynamicImport: true,
      title: 'umi demo',
      dll: false,
      
      routes: {
        exclude: [
          /components\//,
        ],
      },
    }],
  ],
}
```

and project dependencies is

```
"dependencies": {
        "dva": "^2.4.1",
        "react": "^16.8.6",
        "react-dom": "^16.8.6"
      },
```

in redux devtools it saw me like this **@@dva:0** not saw any namespace

```
    state:
@@dva: 0
loading: {global: false, models: {…}, effects: {…}}
routing: {location: {…}}
[[Prototype]]: Object
staticContext: undefined
[[Prototype]]: Object
```

any idia how to solve or what is the problem in my code ?

Comment: when i print console.log(props.state) then it empty

Comment: when i try to same code on windows-10 os then it working ,only problem is it not working on ubuntu os.